# May I write a novel based on another novel?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

Like if I want to write a book series about *Harry Potter* character Rita Skeeter's life, may I do it? I always hear that this isn't allowed. But as far as I know some people have written a book about what happened after Potter won the war. And the series "män som hatar kvinnor" has a fourth book called "Det som inte dödar oss".

So is it allowed to write a book (and make money with it), if you base the plot and/or the characters on something written in another book?

Comment: Can you provide any reference or examples of published "fan fiction" like those you claim exist for *Harry Potter*?

Comment: You can, of course, just write a book about a different journalist in a different magical world. You would have to change the names and enough of the details of the background that it isn’t obviously based on the Harry Potter books.

Comment: Ask Philip Jose Farmer. "The real log of Phileas Fogg" describes what _really_ happened in 80 days around the world (I mean who would seriously believe that this guy wouldn't know what happens when you cross the dateline?) I think Tarzan is also in one of his books.

Comment: @gnasher729 But those works came out of copyright in the US 56 years after publication, before Farmer used those characters. So it’s not relevant to discussion of fiction based on works that are still in copyright.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you are referring to works commonly called "fan fiction."  Under copyright law these *might* be considered "derivative works" and therefore subject to the rights of the copyright owner.  However, they *might* also qualify for exemption from copyright enforcement under "fair use."

It appears that the legality of fan fiction is not settled law, and the outcome of legal challenges have turned on facts specific to each case.  Decent background on the question is [summarized on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_issues_with_fan_fiction).

Comment: Fanfic being valid fair use would only apply to non-commercial fanfic, right?

Comment: @curiousdannii - no, there are other allowances for fair use like "parody" and "criticism" that can be fully commercial/for-profit.

Comment: But those aren't fanfic. I was asking whether commercial fanfic was possible, not other kinds of commercial fair use which I know can be legal.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Right, I guess if you assume that fanfic is "serious" and "adoring" those wouldn't apply.  (But, for example, I was thinking of *Twilight* and having trouble imagining anything based on it that couldn't be characterized as "parody" even if not intended by the fanfic author.  E.g., what if the original work is self-parody?)

Comment: How does works such was "Wicked," about the wicked witch of the west in the Wizard of Oz fall into this category?

Comment: @TomAu, the situation with _Wicked_ is a bit different, because the original 1900 _The Wonderful Wizard of OZ_ by L. Frank Baum entered the public domain in the '50s.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The issue with commercial vs. noncommercial fanfic is complicated, and not just because commerciality tends to weaken fair use claims in general. A noncommercial fanfic usually targets an audience that is heavily invested in the original, and highly likely to purchase any official sequels that might exist. This is markedly different from the general audience that most commercial works (including the original and your hypothetical) would target. So the noncommercial fanfic has a case for being transformative, and against competing with the original or its sequels.

Answer (score 5):

A recent case explored a new book written by Fredrik Colting a Swedish writer, which used the name and characterization of Holden Caulfield, the main character of *Catcher In The Rye*.  The book was ruled to be derivative and the court issued an injunction preventing it from being marketed or sold in the USA. http://www.nytimes.com/2009/07/02/books/02salinger.html?_r=0